# Copying different structs to byte arrays

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm converting an old Visual BASIC program to C#.   The program sends messages to some industrial machinery over a serial or ethernet line.    To do this it creates a byte array of the message.

The problem is that there are **MANY** (~50) different message formats, each one defined in VB6 as a user-defined type.  For example.

```
Public Type K_QCHECK
    Header As K_HEADER3
    Count As LNG4
    crc As INT2
End Type
```

(LNG4 and INT2's are custom types) Running the VB6 code through an automated translation tool I get a C# struct:

```
public struct K_QCHECK
{
     public K_HEADER3 Header;
     public LNG4 Count;
     public INT2 crc;
}
```

But the old VB6 code copied these to the byte array with an LSet.    This depended on the assumption that the types represented a contiguous block of memory.   But in C# the way stuff is laid-out by the compiler in memory is supposed to a be an implementation detail not accessible to the programmer.

So what's the best way to get the contents of these different structs into a byte array?  I could make each one a class and give it a CopyToByteArray method or operator but there are 50 of these so that seems like a lot of work.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Serialization :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx

Comment: I assumed that Serialization would not produce a byte-for-byte copy of the original data structures because it would probably include metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the right solution, but there is a StructLayoutAttribute which lets you define explicitly how the struct is laid out in memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why do you say it's probably not the right solution?  Searching the web, and SO, virtually all the solutions I've seen involve going into unmanaged code and doing some kind of byte-wise copy.    But few of them mention the pitfall that the the alignment and layout may bear no resemblance to what the coder thought he coded in C#.   Your answer provides an apparent solution to this so it may well be (part of) the right solution.

Comment: The struct implementation is indeed compiler specific. With this attribute we are telling compiler how to do its job, which in general is not a good idea. If, however, given resources constraints, this is the only feasible option, then it is the right solution. When I said "this is probably not the right solution", I meant there are probably other ways to solve it, but they may involve more work of redesigning. Also consider that I do not have the full knowledge of the scope and available resources you possess.

Answer (score 1):

Using these codes you can convert between any `structure` and it's `byte[]` array representation. No need to implement separate method for every structure.

```
    public static byte[] StructureToByteArray<T>(T structure) where T:struct
    {
        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);

        byte[] result = new byte[len];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, true);

        Marshal.Copy(ptr, result, 0, len);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return result;
    }

    public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] buffer) where T:struct
    {
        //int len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        int length = buffer.Length;

        IntPtr i = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);

        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, i, length);

        T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(i, typeof(T));

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(i);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the above assume that the data in the structure is laid-out internally, in memory,  in the same order as in the source code, contiguously, and without padding for alignment?    I don't think those are reliable assumptions in C#.