# How do I make fixed-size byte array user type in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm converting an old Visual BASIC program to C#. It sends messages to some industrial machinery over ethernet. To do this it assembles a stream of bytes from fixed-size user defined chunks.

Most of these chunks are small and in C# it's easy to create structs of a few bytes or ints and control their size and layout using StructLayout's, for example

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
```

...so when we go into unmanaged space to do a bytewise copy we don't have byte order or padding problems.

But some of the VB6 structures are big arrays, for example,

```
Private Type SEND_MSG_BUFFER_320_BYTES
    bytes(0 To 319) As Byte  '320 bytes
End Type
```

and I'm struggling with how to do this in C#.      I can make a fixed size array in a class, e.g.,

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public class SOME_BYTES
  {
      public byte[] b = new byte[320];
  }
```

but to do the byte-wise copy I need to be able to discover the size of this at runtime and System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf returns a **4** for this.

Any suggestions for how do do this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class SOME_BYTES
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=320)]
        public byte[] b;
    }
```

You would initialise it as follows:

```
SOME_BYTES data = new SOME_BYTES {b = new byte[320]};
```

Then you can populate data.b[] and use marshalling to get the data to send. The MarshalAs attribute tells the marshaller what fixed size buffer to use when marshalling the data.

You don't need to use the unsafe fixed keyword to do this kind of thing, and I strongly recommend that you avoid it.

Comment: This does the trick.  I definitely have to read up more on the whole InteropServices / MarshallAs range of services because it looks like I'll be up to my armpits in them for this project!

Answer (score 14):

You can use [fixed size buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) if you're okay with unsafe code, and changing your class into a struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct SomeBytes
{
    public fixed byte MessageData[320];
}
```

Personally I would *try* to avoid all of this if possible. If you're just sending the data over the network, why do you need to "go into unmanaged space"? Can you remove that requirement somehow? (Maybe it's fundamental - but it's not clear from your question.)

Comment: There are over 50 different messages which can be sent to the machinery and each message is assembled at runtime from individual structs of different types.   A struct might have a double, a 16 bit uint, a few bytes, etc.   Going into unmanaged space makes it easy to do a bytewise copy.   See my earlier question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485653/copying-different-structs-to-byte-arrays for more detail.

Comment: @user316117: Doing a bytewise copy tends to make things simpler in the *short* term, but makes it very hard to migrate to different formats in the longer term, in my experience. I generally prefer a more flexible approach to serialization, e.g. protocol buffers.

Comment: I looked at the protocol buffer documentation at  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview and it looks like both ends of the communication link would need to know about the protocol.   The industrial equipment we're talking to is not a PC; there would be no way to program it to accept a new or different format.   I've discussed with management whether they would ever want to migrate to new or different formats in the future and the answer was an unequivocal 'no'.

Comment: @user316117: I assumed you were talking about converting data within the client machine. I still wouldn't force the in-memory layout to be the same as the on-the-network layout. Your choice though, of course... it's just not one I'd make.

Comment: What's the alternative, given that the on-the-network layout is set in stone and the .Net Socket.Send method is expecting a buffer with that data.

Comment: @user316117: You build the byte array *when you want to serialize* and only at that point, e.g. using `BinaryWriter`. That makes the format a lot clearer, IMO.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a fixed-size array:

```
unsafe struct SomeBytes {
    public fixed byte b[320];
}
```

Comment: Well, this does seem to work.    I wasn't familiar with the "unsafe" keyword and found out that to use it you have to build with "/unsafe" for the build properties of the project, which turns off bounds-checking and maybe other stuff for the whole program.    It's one thing to go into unsafe mode for a few methods that I write and fully understand, but I'm a little nervous about setting "/unsafe" for a whole program of almost 200K lines of code.    What do other people think?

Comment: @user316117 /unsafe doesn't change anything in project except it allows the use of unsafe code.