# Marshalling variable size packet

Tags: c#, marshalling

This question is somewhat extension of a question asked previously [c# using marshalling for packet parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226463/c-sharp-using-marshalling-for-packet-parsing) by me.
I have to parse a variable size packet although header size is fixed but data packets inside it can be of different size and may be of more than 1 type are present in same packet.

For example the packet has following fields in its header :

```
1) username(12 bytes)
2 password(12 bytes)
3) id_number(4 bytes)
4) may be 1 or combination of other data packets of variable size(size can be 12, 16 or 512 bytes)
5) crc(2 bytes)
```

Now data packets can be following

```
a) data packet type 1
1) size(2 bytes)
2) name(12 bytes)
3) id_number(2 bytes)

b) data packet type 2
1) size(2 bytes)
2) data(24 bytes)
3) id_number(1 byte).
```

So there can be either type1 or type2. It is also possible for both type to be present. My question is how can I use marshalling to parse these packets or anyone can suggest some other way. 
One more thing I want to add is that 1st and 3rd field of data packets will always be the data packet size(2 bytes) and data packet id number(1 byte) respectively. The 2nd field of data packets can be anything and of variable size(2, 3, 13, 18, 515).

Comment: _size can be 12, 16 or 512 bytes_ 2 questions: 1. What is structure of the data packet with size 12? 2. 12, 16 and 512 are the only possible sizes or there could be values in between 16 and 512?

Comment: data packets size can be 5, 6, 16, 21, 518.

Comment: So is field #4 in your header a 2-byte short integer? 4-byte integer?

Comment: You'll have to use BinaryReader to convert the packet.  No big deal.

Comment: field number 4 are the data packets one after another. So their may 1,2,3,..50 or more data packets. Thus total size of field 4 is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you may use LINQ (assuming that ASCII encoding is being used):

```
var packet = new byte[]{
    97, 108, 101, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // username
    112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, //password
    49, 50, 51, 0, // id_number
    0, 53, 0, 0, 1, // 1st data packet
    0, 54, 1, 2, 5, 2, // 2nd data packet
    49, 0 // crc
};

var username = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet.Take(12).ToArray());
var password = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet.Skip(12).Take(12).ToArray());
var idNumber = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet.Skip(24).Take(4).ToArray());
var data = packet.Skip(28).Take(packet.Length - 30).ToArray();
var crc = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet.Skip(packet.Length - 2).ToArray());

var nextDataPackedPos = 0;
var nextDataPackedPos = 0;
var dataPackets = data
    .TakeWhile(b => nextDataPackedPos < data.Length)
    .Zip(data.Skip(nextDataPackedPos), (a, b) =>
    {
        var size = Int32.Parse(
        Encoding.ASCII
            .GetString(data.Skip(nextDataPackedPos).Take(2).ToArray())
            .Trim('\0')
        );
        var result = data.Skip(nextDataPackedPos).Take(size).ToArray();
        nextDataPackedPos += size;
        return result;
    }).ToList();
```

The code first separates the data section from the packet bytes. Then it reads the size of each packet and based on it, it creates an equaly sized array containing the bytes of the data packet. It hen advances to the beginning of the next packet until the end of the array is reached.

Comment: Thanks Alex your solution is looking correct. Let me try out in my code.